# Why is $\log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$ odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, even-and-odd-functions

$$f(x) = \log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$$
I can't figure out, why this function is odd. I mean, of course, its graph shows, it's odd, but when I investigated $f(-x)$, I couldn't find way to $-\log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$.

Comment: $f(x) = \log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x) = \text{ArcSinh}(x) $

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If$$f(x) = \log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$$ then
$$f(-x) = \log \left(\sqrt{(-x)^2+1}-x\right)=$$
$$= \log \left((\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\right)=$$
$$= \log  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\right)=- \log({\sqrt{x^2+1}+x})=-f(x)$$

Comment: easy! nice answer +1

Answer (score 91):

Hint: $(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) = 1$.

Comment: I am so surprised by your nice, simple complete answer Dan. :-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh Wow, this is unexpected. Thank you very much!

Comment: that's why I love math

Answer (score 19):

We have $f(-x)=\log \left(\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)}{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)}\right)=\log\left(\frac{x^2+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\right)=-\log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: Interestingly, I had exactly the same answer as Adi Dani one minute before, and I get 9 upvotes while he/she gets 76...

Comment: Thanks julien for your kind words. +100

Answer (score 8):

Another thing to add is that the Taylor series (of odd functions, if it exists) has only odd powers

$$ x-{\frac {1}{6}}{x}^{3}+{\frac {3}{40}}{x}^{5}+\dots.$$

Comment: Odd answer for the odd function. ;-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Offcourse, we are taking about odd functions.

Answer (score 5):

This function is another command for showing $f(x)=\text{arcsinh}(x)$ being increasing continous in $[0,\infty]$. We know that $f(x)=\sinh(x)$ is an odd one-one function. $$f(x)=\text{arcsinh(x)}\to \sinh(f(x))=x$$ so if $x\to -x$ then $$\sinh(f(-x))=-x\longrightarrow -\sinh(f(-x))=x\longrightarrow\sinh(-f(-x))=x=\sinh(f(x))$$ so $f(-x)=-f(x)$. This means $f(x)$ is an odd function. There is another different approach for this. See this link http://ddmf.msr-inria.inria.fr/1.8/ddmf

[image]

Comment: +1 for your nice alternative approach, and for your kind words.

Comment: I like! Helpful, too!

Comment: The link is not valid

Answer (score 5):

To add another hint to Dan's answer, consider that $-\log a = \log \frac1a$ and then simplify the radical out of the denominator for your function.

Answer (score 4):

Note by differentiating that
$$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}.$$
The result now follows from the fact that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$ is even.

Comment: It is also crucial that the integral start at $0$ and not someplace else.